# How can i use substring in appropriate way?

Tags: c++, string, substring

When i try to print parts of string using `substr()` i got error titled by "out of range" , how can i fix this problem.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int cut;
    string n;
    cout << "Enter string: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter size to cut: " << endl;
    cin >> cut;
    string res;
    int deli = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
    {

        res = n.substr(deli,cut);
        cout << "The deli is: " << deli << endl;
        deli+=cut;

        cout << res << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change your loop to stop when the position to cut at is bigger than  or the same size of the string instead of using `i` because `cut` can be bigger than 1, something like:

```
while(deli < n.size())
{
    res = n.substr(deli,cut);
    cout << "The deli is: " << deli << endl;
    deli+=cut;

    cout << res << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error (exception) is rather informative:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 8) > this->size() (which is 7)
```

so you know that you are accessing memory that string of yours (`n` (also why call it `n`, and not `str`, for example? Anyway.)). When you do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
```

and then request the substring, when you reach towards the end, you go out of range, since you go one by one (`i++`), **regardless of what `deli`'s value is. However, `deli` grows according to the value of `cut`, thus you should check if `deli` is less that the size of your initial string to keep looping.

Minimal working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int cut;
    string n;
    cout << "Enter string: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter size to cut: " << endl;
    cin >> cut;
    string res;
    unsigned int deli = 0;
    do {
      res = n.substr(deli,cut);
      cout << "The deli is: " << deli << endl;
      deli += cut;
      cout << res << endl;
    } while (deli < n.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter string: Stackoverflow
Enter size to cut: 5
The deli is: 0
Stack
The deli is: 5
overf
The deli is: 10
low
```